# Python post cookie with requests

Tags: python, ssl, cookies, python-requests

This is my login page (it's Elastix PBX)
I would like to login with headless browser to retrieve reports.

No matter how many variations I've tried
I still can't access.

With my previous PBX that was not working with SSL that was an easy task
but I can't figure out how to do that with SSL.

**This is my Python code :**

```
import requests

payload = {'input_user': 'admin', 'input_pass': 'pass', 'action':'submit_login'}

r1 = requests.post('https://10.8.20.3/index.php', data=payload, verify=False)
r2 = requests.post('https://10.8.20.3/index.php', cookies=r1.cookies, verify=False)

print r2.text
```

I expected to see my restricted page when printing r2.text
but I actually getting the same login page.

**This is my HTML login page :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Elastix - Login page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/elastixneo/login_styles.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-upl-blockUI.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-upl-colResizable-1.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-upl-colorpicker.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='libs/js/jquery/jquery-upl-easing.1.3.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='libs/js/jquery/widgetcss/colorpicker.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='libs/js/jquery/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      <div id="neo-login-box">
        <div id="neo-login-logo">
          <img src="themes/elastixneo/images/elastix_logo_mini.png" width="200" height="62" alt="elastix logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="neo-login-line">
          <div class="neo-login-label">Username:</div>
          <div class="neo-login-inputbox"><input type="text" id="input_user" name="input_user" class="neo-login-input" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="neo-login-line">
          <div class="neo-login-label">Password:</div>
          <div class="neo-login-inputbox"><input type="password" name="input_pass" class="neo-login-input" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="neo-login-line">
          <div class="neo-login-label"></div>
          <div class="neo-login-inputbox"><input type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Submit" class="neo-login-submit" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="neo-footernote"><a href="http://www.elastix.org" style="text-decoration: none;" target='_blank'>Elastix</a> is licensed under <a href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php" style="text-decoration: none;" target='_blank'>GPL</a> by <a href="http://www.palosanto.com" style="text-decoration: none;" target='_blank'>PaloSanto Solutions</a>. 2006 - 2015.</div>
        <br>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("#neo-login-box").draggable();
            });
            document.getElementById("input_user").focus();
        </script>

      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that you need Javascript for these pages. requests only implements a very basic HTTP client and does not provide Javascript.

Comment: What is the server response when you assign r1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `POST` does not post any data to the server and the first `POST` should probably be a `GET`.

Also, try making the first request a `GET` within a session, then perform the `POST` with the login credentials. Using a session eliminates the need for you to explicitly manage the cookies.

```
import requests

url = 'https://10.8.20.3/index.php'
payload = {'input_user': 'admin', 'input_pass': 'pass', 'action':'submit_login'}

s = requests.session()
r = s.get(url, verify=False)
r = s.post(url, data=payload, verify=False)

print r.text
```

I am not sure that you need to set `verify=False`; if my recommendation works you could try removing it.

Comment: It didn't worked, why do you overwrite r ? first assign r to s.get and then overwrite it with s.post

Comment: And regarding verify=False, since the local server is using a self-signed SSL cert, I most force it to ignore it and not verify the certification.

Comment: @Y.Eliash: OK with the SSL, just wasn't sure whether you thought that SSL had something to do with the problem, so in the case of self signed cert, yes, set `verify=False`.

Comment: Overwriting `r` doesn't matter, it is the response from the `POST` that matters. The initial `GET` is to initialise any cookies, if there are any coming from the server, and store them in the session. You could check the response from the initial `GET` to see what HTTP response you are getting. Likewise for the `POST`.

Comment: Well... it work now ! After I've disabled SSL (HTTPS) I've swapped the POST/GET (first POST for Login and then GET for data extraction) the code is working  - many thanks !